# Can't include "self" in Objective-C description method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a very straight forward class with mostly NSString type properties. In it, I wrote a trivial implementation of the description method. I found that whenever I try to include "self" in the description, it crashes my iPhone app. An example is something such as the following:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    NSString *result;

    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"me: %@\nsomeVar: %@", self, self.someVar];

    return result;
}
```

As soon as I remove the first parameter to the format string, self, it works as expected.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `%p` for `self`, then it will display the address of `self`. If you use `%@`, then it will call `description` on `self`, which will set up an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [super description] instead of self to avoid the infinite recursion, like so:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", [super description], [self someVar]];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You do realise that sets up an infinite recursion.

Your `description` implementation is implicitly calling itself when you pass in `self`, which then calls itself, and so on.

Your crash is mostly likely due to stack space running out... a "stackoverflow" if you will. Fitting considering the site :-)